# What is the cheapest mode of transportation to DCA for a 6AM flight?

Tags: public-transport, airports, washington-dc

The metro isn't open that early, and I want to be there early enough to get through security in time. I've used Uber before, but the fare was quite expensive. I live in the Van Ness area, and am not especially familiar with other taxi services. Based on your experiences, which would you recommend?

Comment: Hitch Hiking would be your cheapest option, along with walking... May also depend where in DC you're starting from?

Comment: I don't think you can [slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slugging) to DCA, at least not in the morning.

Answer (score 2):

There are shared airport shuttles from Van Ness to National that early. [Super Shuttle](http://www.supershuttle.com/) fare is about $14, there may be other shuttle companies.